# commutation relations for many-body permanents

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator, many-body, bosons

I'm interested in understanding the many-body generalization of the canonical commutation relations.  I.e. commutators of the form $$ [a^\dagger_I, a_J]  $$  where $I,J$
 are multi-indices with the same weight $|I|_0=|J|_0=N$ and the $a,a^\dagger$ are boson annihilation/creation operators.

*edit*: By multi index, I mean, $$a_I = \prod_{j=i}^m (a_j)^{I_j}=(a_1)^{I_1}...(a_m)^{I_m}\ \ \ \ \sum_{j=i}^m I_m=|I|_0=N $$

This seems like a natural question, but I haven't been able to find anything about them.  Perhaps "many-body" and "permanent" are not the right keywords.

Without a relevant reference, I'm trying to compute these by hand. Its not hard to see that this result can be constructed by considering a somewhat simple commutator: $$ [(a^\dagger)^N, a^N]$$
Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find or solve this one either.  Its tantalizingly close though. Noting that $[a^\dagger, f(a)]=f'(a)$ for analytic functions $f$, we can take higher derivatives by nesting commutators: $[a^\dagger,[a^\dagger,f(a)]]=f''(a)$, etc.
But using basic results about ring commutators, solving $ [(a^\dagger)^N, a^N]$ involves nested *anticommutators* $$\{a^\dagger,\{a^\dagger,\{...,[a^\dagger,f(a)]\} \} $$

I've played around with it a little bit, and it looks like a nested version of the product rule, but I can't quite find the pattern to write down the general solution.

Any advice? either a (partial) solution, a link to a relevant reference, or even some suggested key words would be great appreciated.  This is surely a well studied problem, I just don't know how to plug into it.

Comment: To be clear, are you trying to find $[\sum_k M_{ik} a_k^\dagger, \sum_k M_{jk}^*a_k]$, where the $a_k$ are single-site annihilation operators? Because I'm not sure what the phrase "I,J are multi-indices with the same weight" is supposed to mean here.

Comment: I edited to clarify.  I'm considering monomials of creation/annihilation  operators.

Comment: A permanent is a polynomial of degree $n$ symmetric is the entries of an $n\times n$ matrix.  Can you clarify how you see your $a_I$ as a permanent?

Comment: Taken as boson operators,   $|I>=a^\dagger_I |0>$.  If you have a suggestion for better notation, please suggest it.  Part of the reason I can't find much on this is that I'm using nonstandard terminology for sure.